# OAuth 1.0 using Consumer Key and Consumer Secret in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth

I am making an application that requires oAuth 1.0 authentication. I have access to consumer key and consumer secret given by the client. I have tried to do it with AFNetworking but it has not come up well. 
Could someone suggest me a good tutorial for the same. Actually I am getting an error for unauthenticated user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. First of all I used AFNetworking and AFOauth1Client for the same.

```
 AFOAuth1Client * client = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:<your URL>] key:<Your Consumer Key> secret:<Your Consumer Secret>];
[client setOauthAccessMethod:@"POST"];
[client setSignatureMethod:AFHMACSHA1SignatureMethod];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
```

Next I created a request for this client and set the Body of the request

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request =[client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:<URL Path> parameters:nil];
                                        //here path is actually the name of the method    


[request setHTTPBody:[<Your String Data> dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then I made use of AFHttpRequestOperation with the request made in the upper step

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // Success Print the response body in text
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        //parsing the xml Response
        NSXMLParser * parser= [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseObject];

        [parser setDelegate:self];

        [parser parse];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //Something Went wrong..
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
```